# Can I make this keyboard light command that requires sudo run at startup?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, startup

My laptop has a light under the keyboard. I doubt the keyboard light consumes a lot of power, but when it comes to laptops and batteries, every little bit helps. So I prefer it to default to being off.

I found this command that I can run at the command line which switches off the keyboard light:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Which is nice, but I'd like to have it in my list of startup programs so that I don't have to remember to turn off the keyboard light, which I often forget to do.

However, it doesn't seem to work if I put it in the startup applications, and I suspect that it could be because part of it requires `sudo`, so it probably doesn't have the right persmissions at startup time. Or maybe it's another issue. In any case, it doesn't run at startup.

Is there a way I can get this command to run at startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get this command to run at startup?

Yes,

you can add this command in rc.local file in order to be executed in ever system boot/or reboot.

Edit the file, you will need root privileges for that.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the command line before `exit 0`

The file should read

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
exit 0
```

save the file and reboot to check the results. No `sudo` is needed here, because the file is executed by the `root` user.

I don't remember what the execution bits are by default (in Ubuntu) at this file, but you can add the execution bit with the following command

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: This solution worked after upgrading to 14.04.