# Using /etc/rc.local to turn off keyboard backlight no longer working in 15.04

Tags: keyboard, brightness, asus, 15.04

I have an Asus laptop, and the keyboard backlight comes on full at startup.  I formerly used the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/415145/can-i-make-this-keyboard-light-command-that-requires-sudo-run-at-startup) to issue a sudo command to turn it off. Basically, the steps were:

1. `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
2. put `echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness` before `exit 0`
3. Save and `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

On upgrade to 15.04, this stopped working.  And I can't seem to fix it.  Any ideas???

Comment: This covers the same ground as http://askubuntu.com/questions/623566/ .

Comment: @MBWD refer here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/366578/start-asus-laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/366578/start-asus-laptop-ux32vd-with-keyboard-backlight-off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the new systemd. try:

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

To check status:

```
systemctl status rc-local.service
```

make sure that /etc/rc.local is executable and has `#!/bin/sh` in the first line.

Comment: Oh.  That makes sense.  FYI to future readers.  When I entered `systemctl enable rc-local.service.` I got:  `The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed.` But when I checked the status, it did say active.  Restarting now to see if if worked.

Comment: It did not work.  

Here is the text of `rc.local` file: 
`!/bin/sh -e  sleep 15s
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
exit 0`

It is executable.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still is not working -- even though `rc-local.service` has a status of `active (exited)`.  Here is what I now have in the rc.local file:  
`#!/bin/sh -e`
`(sleep 10 && echo 562 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)` 
`(sleep 5 && echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness)`
`exit 0`

Comment: This worked under 16.04.  First `systemctl enable rc-local.service`.  Then paste this into `/etc/rc.local` --- `#!/bin/sh -e
(sleep 20 && echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness)
exit 0`.   Then make `/etc/rc.local` executable with `sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`.  Finally, to check enter `systemctl status rc-local.service`.  If all is working it should show green and active.